# Grouping and functions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

In `dplyr`, I want to apply a function conditional on the groups that I previously selected. However, the function is always calculated for the complete data. A minimal example:

```
func_a = function(data_a) {
  value = mean(data_a$V2)
  return(value)
}  

data = as.data.frame(cbind(c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), c(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
data$V2=as.numeric(data$V2)
```

> ```
> data
> V1 V2
> a  1
> a  2
> a  3
> b  4
> b  5
> b  6
> ```

```
o = data %>% group_by(V1) %>% dplyr::mutate(test = func_a(.))

o$test
[1] 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5
```

I would have expected/desired:

```
[1] 2 2 2 5 5 5
```

The mean function is a primitive example, `dplyr::mutate(test = mean(V2))` would do the job, clearly. There are, however, other functions that cannot be used like that.

The main point of this question is how to transfer a slice of the data frame to a function instead of the whole one.

Comment: As written, there are functions which cannot be applied like this, so yes, it's a must.

Comment: You've written your function wrongly. It should be something like `func_a = function(x) mean(x)` and then you could call it using `data %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(test = func_a(V2))` or if you want it to run over all the cols `data %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate_all(funs(func_a))` unless you want it to run over `V2` without you telling it to? In that case you will probably need to mess around with `lazyval` package.

Comment: Thanks David, I am still fighting a bit with the logic of this, but it works. Happily, I will accept your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidArenburg commented, the way your function works is not how `dplyr` is designed to work. The `.` explicitly means the full variable (data.frame in this case) being passed through the `%>%`. I have used this hack occasionally if I want to do something on the full data, and something on the group, e.g.

```
data %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(eg = mean(V2) / mean(.$V2))
```

gives

```
      V1    V2        eg
  <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1      a     1 0.5714286
2      a     2 0.5714286
3      a     3 0.5714286
4      b     4 1.4285714
5      b     5 1.4285714
6      b     6 1.4285714
```

Therefore, the best solution to get `mutate` to apply the grouping, is to pass column name(s) instead, e.g.,

```
func_forColumn = function(data_a) {
  value = mean(data_a)
  return(value)
}  

data %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(test = func_forColumn(V2))
```

gives

```
      V1    V2  test
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     1     2
2      a     2     2
3      a     3     2
4      b     4     5
5      b     5     5
6      b     6     5
```

If you really need to be able to pass in the full data.frame (e.g., you are working with functions written for an old paradigm and can't update them for some reason), you could either use `split`/`lapply` like I assume you used to, then just `bind_rows` the result, like so:

```
data %>%
  split(.$V1) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    x %>%
      mutate(test = func_a(.))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

which gives

```
  V1 V2 test
1  a  1    2
2  a  2    2
3  a  3    2
4  b  4    5
5  b  5    5
6  b  6    5
```

or, you can use `do` which allows somewhat more complicated grouping/summary outputs. This is designed to allow multi-column return in data.frames, but can be adapted for your scenario:

```
data %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  do(as.data.frame(func_a(.)))
```

gives

```
     V1 `func_a(.)`
  <fctr>       <dbl>
1      a           2
2      b           5
```

Note that it only returns one line per group. So, you would need to use a join (e.g `left_join`) to the original data if you wanted one line per original entry.

Here is a more typical example of the use of `do`, which might be more closely related to the reason your functions are expecting a full data.frame in the first place.

```
mySummary <- function(x){
  as.data.frame(rbind(summary(x)))
}

data %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  do(mySummary(.$V2))
```

gives

```
     V1  Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
  <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     1       1.5      2     2       2.5     3
2      b     4       4.5      5     5       5.5     6
```